# HttpModule: Como tratar erros de HttpApplication sem HttpContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpapplication

Venho encontrando uma situação particularmente interessante. Tenho uma rotina genérica de tratamento de erro implementada dentro de um `HttpModule`, e recentemente eu percebi um comportamento estranho: O evento `HttpApplication.Error` é disparado, mas `HttpContext.Current` é `null`.

**Esta é a parte relevante do HttpModule:**

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.Error += context_Error;
    context.PostMapRequestHandler += context_PostMapRequestHandler;

}

void context_PostMapRequestHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var aux = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
    if (aux != null) aux.Error += context_Error;
}

void context_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _localLog.Add("HttpApplication error handler reached.");
    try
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
        {
            _localLog.Add("No HttpContext.");
        }
        else
        {
            var objError = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();

            if (objError == null)
            {
                _localLog.Add("GetLastError(): no error.");
                return;
            }

            //[Proper error handler follows here...]
        }
    }
}
```

**E o evento aparece da seguinte maneira:**

[image]

Uma possibilidade é que a *exception* esteja sendo gerada em uma *thread* fora de contexto.

De qualquer maneira, como posso interceptar este erro a fim de tratá-lo?

<sup>Crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018273/httpmodule-how-to-handle-httpapplication-errors-without-httpcontext</sup>

Answer (score 0):

No método context_Error podes fazer cast do parâmetro sender para HttpApplication e aí aceder à propriedade Context. Também pode acontecer que seja uma excepção que ocorra sem que haja nenhum pedido HTTP, por exemplo, código de inicialização/warmup da aplicação web.

Comment: Ponto interessante, Ricardo! Obrigado  pela sugestão, eu vou testar o cast para HttpApplication.